# デバッグビルドしたiOSアプリにおいて位置情報の取得が出来ない。

Tags: monaca

機種名:iPhone5
OSのver:8.13

表題の通り、デバッグビルドしたアプリの位置情報が取得できず困っています。
ioSのMonacaデバッガー上およびAndroid版では問題なく取得出来ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ビルドしたアプリでは、上図の様に位置情報の利用を「常に許可」を入れてアプリを起動を行うとこのチェックが外れてしまい位置情報の取得ができなくなります。何度チェックを入れてもアプリを起動する度立ち上げる度にチェックが外れてしまい、位置情報の取得が出来ません。
尚、iosのverを8.2にでも試してみましたが同じでした。

解決法やヒントが分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

iOS8から位置情報の取得方法が変わっていますが、その辺りに問題は無さそうでしょうか？
[iOS 8から位置情報を取得する方法が変わるよ](http://qiita.com/koogawa/items/6ec24ca3201977e9642b)

その他注意点
[iOS8対応時の注意点まとめ](http://qiita.com/peromasamune/items/dc7f51b691b992a56e50)

Comment: 参考リンクありがとうございます。
info.plistに下記を加えたら無事位置情報が取得出来るようになりました。

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Answer (score 0):

Cordova3.5だとCordovaのバグでiOS8.1系で位置取得ができないようです。この現象はCordovaのGeolocationプラグインver 0.3.08で発生するようです。Goldプランでないと、できない方法ですが下記のページから直接Geolocationプラグインをダウンロードして組み込むことで正常に位置情報を取得できるようになりました。Monacaサポートには既に報告済みです。

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/tree/r0.3.10