# iOSシミュレーターでマップ表示ができない

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

Xcodeを使い、iphoneアプリを作ろうと考えています。
しかし、iOSシミュレータでマップ表示がうまくいかずつまづいています。
locationはappleを指定しております。
iOS7.1ではマップ表示がされ、現在地もappleとなって動作する。
iOS8.2や8.3ではマップが表示されず、罫線のみの表示となっていまいます。

MacOSはYosemite version10.10.3
Xcodeのversionは6.3.2

ご教授お願いいたしいます。

Comment: iOS8.xでうまく動かないということであれば、この辺が参考になるかもしれません。
http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7865